# What possible combinations of single-rooms, double-rooms and triple-rooms

Tags: combinatorics

*A sports association with 40 persons want to book a hotel. The hotel have single-rooms for 40 euros , double-rooms for 60 euros and triple-rooms for   70 euros. What possible combination of single-rooms, double-rooms and triple-rooms exist if every person should get a bed and the total cost should be exactly 1220 euros.*

I tried to solve this problem but I'm stuck.

$40x + 60y + 70z = 1220$

$x + 2y + 3z = 40$

Anyone got any better solution?

The correct answer is: 6,14,2

Comment: I have nothing to show mr Lee, i dont know to solve this got any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the standard linear algebra method for finding all solutions to that system of linear equations? If so, it won't then be hard to determine which of those solutions consist of three nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations are good ones.  As you have two equations in three unknowns you expect a one dimensional continuum of solutions over the real numbers.  The requirement that the variables be natural numbers will pick out a few of these.  If you multiply the second by $30
$ and subtract from the first you are left with 
$$10x-20z=20$$
which gives $x=2+2z$.  Plugging that into the second gives $$2+2z+2y+3z=40\\2y+5z=38\\y=\frac {38-5z}2$$
So $z$ must be even to make $y$ come out integral and can be no greater than $6$ to let $y$ be positive.

We get solutions $(2,19,0), (6,14,2), (10,9,4), (14,4,6)$.  I don't see how you choose one of these over another.